# Interpretation of interaction (time x intervention) in an intervention study when baseline values are unequal

Tags: regression, bayesian, intervention-analysis

I came across an intervention study that measured a significant decrease in a specific treatment group. However the starting conditions where not the same and are like*:

[image: example of interaction effect mostly in different start conditions]

So there is a difference between group a and b, but it was before the intervention that the two groups differed.

I imagine that such interaction 'effect' can be likely something like regression to the mean and that, given the null hypothesis is true, the observation of an effect is more likely when the starting conditions were different (since the changes correlate with the starting condition, a higher starting value is more likely to decrease).

So I simulated ten thousand data sets for a 2x2 design based on a null hypothesis that all four groups are the same. I computed p-values of two t-tests.

- One for the difference in the starting conditions.
- One for the difference in the change between time points $0$ and $1$.

I created a scatter plot for the p-value of the second t-test conditional on the p-value of the first t-test (I used an average of the second t-test, conditional on binned p-values of the first t-test).

[image: example of different mean p conditional on starting conditions]

And it appears that we observe a lower p-value for the interaction effect, when we already have a low p-value for the t-test of the starting conditions.

If the starting conditions are different, then we are more likely to observe a significant interaction effect (assuming that the null hypothesis is true).

**Question:** Are there methods (asside from ensuring equal starting conditions during the assignment of treatments/interventions) that correct for this sort of regression to the mean? Are there examples of types of analyses, like hypothesis tests, that have accounted for this effect? For example, possibly a Bayesian approach will be less influenced by differences in starting conditions?

---

*: The example here is simplified. The specific data and study are from Figures 2S and 3S from the supplemental information of the study ["Cardiometabolic health improvements upon dietary intervention are driven by tissue-specific insulin resistance phenotype: A precision nutrition trial"](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cmet.2022.12.002) by Trouwborst et. al.

**: code for images

```r
set.seed(1)

sim = function(n=10) {
  y0a = rnorm(n,2)
  y0b = rnorm(n,2)
  y1a = rnorm(n,2)
  y1b = rnorm(n,2)

  p_start = t.test(y0a,y0b)$p.value
  p_exp = t.test(y1a-y0a,y1b-y0b)$p.value

  return(c(p_start, p_exp))
}


p = replicate(10^4,sim())

pc = seq(0,1,0.05)
k = length(pc)-1 ### number of bins
conditional_p = rep(0,k)
p_condition = (pc[-1]+pc[-(k+1)])/2

for (ki in 1:k) {
   sel = which((p[1,]>pc[ki])*(p[1,]<pc[ki+1]) == 1)
   conditional_p[ki] = mean(p[2,sel])
}

plot(p_condition, conditional_p, 
main = "simulation of 10 000 intervention studies",
xlab = "p-values for t-test of starting conditions",
ylab = "p-values for t-test of intervention" )

### cross effect description 
plot(c(0,1,0,1),c(1,1,1.2,1.01), pch=20, col = c(1,1,2,2), xaxt="n",
ylim = c(0,1.5), xlab = "time",
ylab = "value of interest")
lines(c(0,1),c(1,1))
lines(c(0,1),c(1.2,1.01), col = 2)
axis(1,at =c(0,1))

text(0.5,1.1, "group B", col = 2, pos = 3)
text(0.5,1, "group A", col = 1, pos = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

To correct for baseline imbalance, we can add the baseline as a covariate. If we do this, then the baseline has no influence anymore on the p-value of the test for the difference between the change in the effect group and control group.

We can see this in a plot of simulations below which are created based on the individuals being drawn from the same normal distribution.

[image: comparison of dependency on baseline imbalance]

On the two images, the p-value of the test that compares the treatment and control is plotted on the vertical axis. On the right it is not dependent on the p-value of a t-test for the baseline value. On the left it is.

Interestingly, when we look at the power and create simulations of the situation when an effect is actually present, then we see that the test that includes the baseline as a covariate has more power.

[image: difference between power]

---

```r
set.seed(1)

sim = function(n = 10, effect = 0) {

  ### create data
  x = rep(c(0,1),n/2)       # control/treatment    
  y0 = rnorm(n)             # value before
  y1 = rnorm(n) + effect*x  # value after

  ### t-test for baseline difference 
  p_start = t.test(y0[x==0], 
  y0[x==1])$p.value

  ### tests for effect of 'x'
  ### mod2 has a correction of the baseline value y0
  mod1 = lm(y0-y1 ~ 1 + x)
  mod2 = lm(y0-y1 ~ 1 + x + y0)
  p_1 = summary(mod1)$coefficients[2,4]
  p_2 = summary(mod2)$coefficients[2,4]
  return(c(p_start,p_1,p_2))
}


### 10000 simulations
p = replicate(10^3,sim())

### plot values to check dependency 
plot(p[1,],p[2,], pch = 20, cex = 0.7, 
     xlab = "p-value baseline t-test", 
     ylab = "p-value effect test", 
     main = "no correction baseline")
plot(p[1,],p[3,], pch = 20, cex = 0.7,
     xlab = "p-value baseline t-test",
     ylab = "p-value effect test",
     main = "baseline as covariate")

### computations with different effect sizes
### to check difference in power
effect_size = seq(0,1,0.1)
power = sapply(effect_size, FUN = function(eff) {
   p = replicate(10^3,sim(effect = eff))
   power1 = mean(p[2,] < 0.05)
   power2 = mean(p[3,] < 0.05)
   return(c(power1,power2))
})
    
plot(effect_size, power[2,], col = 2, ylab = "power")
points(effect_size, power[1,], col = 1)
legend(0,0.2, c("uncorrected","corrected"), col = c(1,2), pch = c(1,1))
```

If I adjust the code a bit by adding a random effect for the individual, then the difference in the improvement of the power decreases as the random effect increases. This is because the slope/correlation between the baseline difference and the effect size decreases.

```r
sim = function(n = 10, effect = 0, random_effect = 0.3) {
  x = rep(c(0,1),n/2)
  id = rep(c(1,n/2),each = 2)
  re = rnorm(n/2,0,random_effect)
  y0 = rnorm(n) + re[id]
  y1 = rnorm(n) + effect*x + re[id]
```

Comment: I often see studies that include covariates like age and gender in a linear model. But I don't see so often corrections for a difference in baseline of the dependent variables.

Comment: The so called ANCOVA model where baseline measurements are included as a covariate is the defacto gold standard for analyzing randomized trials with a baseline and follow-up (see [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1136/bmj.323.7321.1123), for example). At least this is my current state of knowledge. It is also [well known](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jclinepi.2007.02.006) that this model has higher power than a simple t-test for the follow-up measurements or a t-test on change-scores ([here](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jclinepi.2006.02.007) is another paper on the topic).

Comment: @COOLSerdash those are nice links, thank you. I am not so much acquainted with this type of statistics and more into the mathematical aspects. Do you believe that this gold standard is also the most used standard? In the linked article they have for instance this table 2 with outcomes at 0 weeks and 12 weeks and they observe all kinds of significant effects for 'group x time', but in a lot of those cases that effect goes along with the baseline being different. The subscript says 'adjusted for age, sex, and center' but not for the baseline difference in the outcome variable. I see this often.

Comment: Good question. I must confess that I don't have a comprehensive overview of the literature. But I can say that it doesn't surprise me to see other, maybe substandard models applied to these kinds of data. What I also see commonly is a mixed effects model that models both the baseline and follow-up. But this doesn't correct for any baseline differences which makes it not a first line choice for me.